Insert images in Google Sheets specific cell with gspread
I would like to insert image to google sheet, like in the attached screenshot.
And following is my code, but it's failed.
cell_list = getsheet.range('A24:I44')
with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
    image_data = f.read()
getsheet.update_cells(cell_list)



In your sample image, it seems that an image is put over the cells. Do you want to put an image over the cells instead of putting it into a cell? Unfortunately, in the current stage, there is no method for putting an image over the cells and for putting it into a cell. In this case, it is required to use Google Apps Script. If you want to use Python script, Google Apps Script can be executed by Python. Is this included in your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your expected result.

Yes, I want to put an image over the cells, for seeing the image quickly and conveniently.  How can I use Google Apps Script? Can it be used with python script? Thanks

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer using Google Apps Script. Please confirm it.

From your following reply,

Yes, I want to put an image over the cells, for seeing the image quickly and conveniently. How can I use Google Apps Script? Can it be used with python script?

The sample scripts of Google Apps Script and Python are as follows.
Usage:
1. Prepare Spreadsheet
Please prepare a Google Spreadsheet and open the script editor.
2. Google Apps Script
Please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor.
function doPost(e) {
  if (!e || !e.postData) {
    console.error("No event object");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No event object");
  }
  const { spreadsheetId, sheetName, row, column, imageData, mimeType } = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).insertImage(`data:${mimeType};base64,${imageData}`, column, row);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}

3. Deploy Web Apps
The detailed information can be seen in the official document.
Please set this using the script editor.

On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
Please select "Me" for "Execute as".
Please select "Anyone" for "Who has access to the app:".

In this sample, as a simple approach, the request can be done without the access token.


Please click "Deploy" button.
On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "Test deployments".
Copy Web Apps URL. It's like https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec.

4. Testing
In order to test this, please use the following Python script. Please set your Web Apps URL to webAppsUrl. And, please set the file and path of the PNG image to file, your Spreadsheet ID, and sheet name to obj.
If your image is Jpeg, please modify mimeType to image/jpeg.
import base64
import json
import requests


file = "sample.png"
webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
obj = {
    "spreadsheetId": "###",
    "sheetName": "Sheet1",
    "row": "2",
    "column": "2",
    "imageData": base64.b64encode(open(file, 'rb').read()).decode('ascii'),
    "mimeType": "image/png"
}
res = requests.post(webAppsUrl, data=json.dumps(obj))
print(res.text)

When this script is run, when the above Web Apps is correctly deployed, an image is put over the cells as the anchor cell "B2".
Note:

If your image size is large, insertImage cannot be used. Please be careful about this. Ref (Author: me) At that time, please use the small size of the image.

This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this to your actual situation.

When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)

